# UnrecognizedPropertyException in JSON with JERSEY

Tags: java, json, rest

We get a org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException with using Jerseys and Jackson as JSON-Mapper. We have an object with not native type as property (for example: not a String or int). When i use the annotation @JsonIgnore it's ok. But I must have the property.

Does anybody, which annotation should I use? In JAXB it's @XMLType?

We use Jersey 1.9.1 and Jackson 1.9.13.

Comment: Check the names of properties and put the getters/setters of all properties

Comment: They are OK. With an earlier version of Jackson it works correctly. It was the version 1.8.3.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and some code?

Comment: I solved this. The annotation org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty was missing at getter/setter. The old version seems to be more tolerant.  It was enough that, the getter be named: getPROPERTYNAME. Now the annotation must be used.

Comment: I don't think that in the new version is required the annotation. I think the problem is the names of the properties and the get/set. Check that one more time. If the property is "oneThing" the get/set must be getOneThing(). I mean, camelcase.

Comment: We don't have the property only the getter. ( it is _getBuldnumber_ in JSON-String we had .... buildnumber:...... ) It worked fine. In the new version we need this annotation.

Comment: `getBuldnumber` is not a correct getter for `buildnumber`. Has it been a typo error?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. See my comment on the question.